# Set an explicitly typed object's key to a variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

What I want to do is to explicitly type an object and then assign key-value pairs to the object where the keys are variable names.

I came up with a solution using ES2015 template literals and `JSON.parse()`.

The solution looks like this:

```
interface MyObj {
    [propName: string]: number;
}

const myVar = 'key';
const objString = `{
    "${myVar}": 1
}`;

const myObj: MyObj = JSON.parse(objString);
```

I believe that this kind of implementation can be somewhat hard to work with later on during development, so is there a prettier or more obvious solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript and Typescript support left-hand variables e.g. `{ [variable]: value }`. They also support adding properties later. e.g. `obj[variable] = value`

So for your example:

```
interface MyObj {
  [propName: string]: number
}

const myVar = 'key';

// option 1
const obj: MyObj = { [myVar]: 1 };

// option 2
const obj: MyObj = {};
obj[myVar] = 1;
```